# SQLException The parameterized query ### which was not supplied

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlexception

I've searched this site, and other sites to understand and get rid of this exception. Many answers, but I can't find where "I'm wrong". This i the exception:

> The parameterized query '(@listenr int,@stregko nvarchar(4000))SELECT
>   * FROM Indkøbsliste' expects the parameter '@stregko', which was not supplied.

And here i my code.

```
    public Indkøbsliste findIndkøbslisteStregkode(string stregko, int listenr)
    {
        Indkøbsliste inl = new Indkøbsliste();



        SqlConnection myCon = DBcon.getInstance().conn();
        myCon.Open();

        string query = "SELECT * FROM Indkøbsliste WHERE Stregkode = @stregko AND ListeNr = @listenr";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, myCon);
        com.Parameters.Add("@stregko", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stregko; 
        com.Parameters.Add("@listenr", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = listenr; 
        SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {

            inl.ListeNr = dr.GetInt32(1);
            inl.Stregkode = dr.GetString(2);
            inl.Navn = dr.GetString(3);
            inl.Antal = dr.GetInt32(4);
            inl.Pris = dr.GetDecimal(5);

        }
        myCon.Close();
        return inl;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `AddWithValue` method

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stregko", stregko);
or 
com.Parameters.Add("@stregko", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = stregko;
or 
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@stregko", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
parameter.Value = stregko;
com.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

rather than

`com.Parameters.Add("@stregko", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stregko;`

Comment: @Anders Jensen - yups after 5 min may be you able to accept it

Comment: @PranayRana - Do not suggest AddWithValue especially when input type is varchar/string. What happen if input exceed the length of table's field?

Answer (score 2):

The SQL query expects a unicode string for `stregko` but you provide a non-unicode string.

Try to change your c# code for assigning the parameter as follows:

```
com.Parameters.Add("@stregko", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = stregko;
```

Note the "N" in NVarChar!

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL parameter is `nvarchar` - try using `System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar` in your C# code.

Answer (score 1):

as from your error message, try to change:

```
com.Parameters.Add("@stregko", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
```

with

```
com.Parameters.Add("@stregko", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the size.

```
com.Parameters.Add("@stregko", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar,50).Value = stregko;
```